# How can I solve the output staggered phenomenon in tmux

Tags: terminal

My system os is 4.0.5 gentoo.

After hours of tmux opening, suddenly it shows output staggered. For example,
The output of `ls -l` will be

```
> 1111
> 1111
> 1111
```

But now it becomes

```
1111
        1111
                    1111
```

How can I solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An application that ran in the terminal has left the terminal in a state where printing a newline only moves the cursor to the next line, but doesn't move it back to the beginning of the line. Restore the terminal settings:

```
stty sane
```

Answer (score 1):

Ncurses comes with a command called `reset` which does pretty much the same thing as `stty sane`.  see `man reset` for details.

Also, many terminal programs have a `Reset` and/or `Reset and Clear` option on the menu if you right-click in the terminal.